# Don't understand the question/solution to a JEE algebra example

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bquHz.png)

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw00t.png)

I've tried to find a relation between z and i but keep getting this from the formula (x/y) = n*y + r (n being the number of times that you can multiply y without exceeding past x and r being the remeinder)[work I've done so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGnP5.jpg)

Comment: In your solution, you have used the same quotient $q$ when dividing by $z-i$ and $z+i$ and that is not right. Moreover, the quotient $q$ need not be just a complex number (so you got to be careful with what you mean by $1/q$ in your attempt).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AnuragA, I apologize. I did realize my mistake with my original approach with the quotient, do I mark this question as solved or delete it? I'll probably end up deleting it since it doens't seem to really add anything to the site. Cheers.

Comment: You're recommended to type the question as well as the solution down using MathJax to make the question more accessible and attract potential people who can help you